# facebook api graph not search users

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to find users but it throws me an authentication error

```
import requests
from urllib.parse import urlencode

token = 'my-token'
graph_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/search?'

params = {
    'q':'francisco',
    'type':'user',
    'method':'get',
    'format':'json',
    'access_token':token
}

url = graph_url+urlencode(params)

resp = requests.get(url)
print(resp.json())
```

error:

```
{'error': {'message': 'Unsupported operation', 'type': 'OAuthException', 'code': 100, 'fbtrace_id': 'Dao1UbelGkF'}}
```

It seems that something I'm not doing well or that searches are no longer allowed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes#search-4-4

Searching for users is not available anymore since 2018. It would not make any sense anyway, you would only be able to get users who authorized your App.

Comment: there is some possibility of looking for people by place? thank

Comment: no, of course not. people who did not authorize your app are none of your business, you cannot get their name or any other info at all, no matter how. and "by place" would be even more problematic if you think about data privacy...no app should know where their users were are where they are right now, without their explicit authorization.

Comment: that's fine, I do not mean to know where they are, it's like having facebook and looking for people, people who have their public profile can be found, I can put a person's name on my facebook and see if it's on facebook, I do not try to make a malicious application, I try to extend my basic application, you are right that nobody should know where we are but if you realize if you put a name on Google go to facebook therefore I do not know how much privacy is

Comment: If it is the same thing then just manually search on Facebook.com

Comment: just because something is public does not mean it´s available with the api.